# data migration Using pentaho spoon

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I am planning to do data migration using Pentaho.

function i want:

1. the data '1' in column A of the [input table]
   change to the data 'Y' in column B of the [output table] and insert it.
2. Data migration when one table is divided into a parent table and child table (1 table -> 2 tables)
3. When multiple tables are merged into one table

Can these three cases be solved using a pentaho spoon?
If so, which function should I use?

I tried

- insert/updqte
- Value Mapper

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use PDI to do that data migration. The steps you need to use in your transformations/workflows are going to depend on the logic of your processes, and there's not only one answer to your questions.

For question 1, yes, a value mapper will work if there are few values to transform, if the number of values increases, maybe maintaining another table/file to store all the maps from ValueOrigin -> ValueDest and then using a Merge join step or a Lookup step would be more efficient.

The insert/update step usually isn't a efficient step for me, I prefer to separate the logic of my loads in three transformations, first I identify which data needs to be inserted and which data needs to be updated, and store that data temporary in two files or tables, then I create the transformation to insert my data and a second transformation to update the data. But that is just one way of doing things that works for me because it's quicker than the insert/update step, with PDI usually there's not only one way of achieving your results.